# mod_rewrite won't remove file extensions with other rewrite rule in place

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite within my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?ID=$1 [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

The code above works but the issue is several of the pages on my site link to files without extensions because our original .htaccess file removed all extensions from every request. My site is built on PHP. Ultimately I want to use the rules above exactly as is but at the end of it all, i want to strip the file extension (.php) from every request.

Is this possible?

Comment: I got now what mistake I was making last night, I was too sleepy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?ID=$1 [QSA,NC,L,R]
```